# Interact two UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my app I have tow webView in different viewController. For more clarify assume that

```
ViewCon1 => WebView1; ~ (HTML Page)
ViewCon2 => WebView2; ~ (HTML Page)
```

When My app will launch then **ViewCon1** will be display and I set **WebView1** as subView of **ViewCon1** with full screen. **WebView1** has it's content that get by `loadRequest`.

Here **ViewCon2's view** is toggle view which has sub view of **WebView2**. `ViewCon2's view` add as subView of **ViewCon1** as toggle view *(hide/show by tap)*. **WebView2** has it's content that get by `loadRequest`. *(I can not present/push **ViewCon2** But I just added it's view as subView of **ViewCon1**)*

> My goal is - I want to load data on **WebView1** whenever I clicked on **WebView2's** Link.

Answer (score 0):

try this `UIWebView` `delegate` method trick.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationTyp{

    if (webView == webView2) {
            [webView1 loadRequest:request];
    }        
    return YES;        
}
```

Comment: Not working my toggle view remove *(converted  to **WebView1**)*

Comment: You should be using `-isEqual:` instead of `==` when comparing Objective-C objects.